# Place a certain row first in ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to change the order of the records resulted from a select.

I want a certain record to be the first in my list, and the other ones after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col = 'something' -- whatever identifies "a certain row"
  THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
  col;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) in `ODRER BY`

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM Table
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN Col1 = @certainrecord THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
, Col1
, Col2
```